# wp condition works in php 7 but not in php 5

Tags: php, wordpress

Below script is working fine in my test server with php 7 but its crashing in the live server with php 5, any idea why?

I am checking if the value of a field type is empty to hide the li if so.

```
<?php if (types_render_field("slug-here") != '') { ?>
    <li class="">
        <a href="<?php echo types_render_field("slug-here"); ?>" taget="_blank">title-here</a>
    </li>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: Please don't use short tags, especially mixing them with regular php opening tags...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<? } ?>` use `<?php } ?>` or

Set

```
short_open_tag=On
```

in `php.ini`

Comment: Thanks, how could I miss that